# MDX IN Or SubQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server, mdx

I am making a sales cube for a bank, I need to do a query with this Dimensions `DimTiempo`, `DimCliente`, `DimCuenta`

I need to find the number of customers who are in `DimCuenta` attribute `[DimCuenta].[Planes].[Cue Nombre Plan]` with value 'APORTES SOCIALES' And besides having another record in the `DimCuenta` with the attribute `[DimCuenta].[Cue Codigo Aplicacion]` with value `'L'` also need to include in the result hierarchy `[Ano Mes]` of `DimTiempo`, I don't know to do this because I Don't know how to do an In or a subquery in MDX,

Comment: Please, try to format better your question and provided some exmaples of what are you doing and needs to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best advise would be to take some time and read about MDX technology. There are a few principles that are different and need to be known.

I'd advise reading some introductions in MDX as this [one](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/gentle_introduction.php). If you're more a reader there are some books on MDX. Sorry, long time I haven't read one can't advise.